# Unset product tabs for specific product categories in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

I am using the code coming from this answer:

[Hiding tabs only for some products in WooCommerce single product pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41369215/hiding-tabs-only-for-some-products-in-woocommerce-single-product-pages/41371399#41371399)

Here is that code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 98 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    // Define HERE your targetted products IDs in this array   <===  <===  <===
    $target_products_ids = array(123,152,162);

    // If the current product have the same ID than one of the defined IDs in your array,… 
    // we remove the tab.
    if(in_array($product_id, $target_products_ids)){

        // KEEP BELOW ONLY THE TABS YOU NEED TO REMOVE   <===  <===  <===  <===
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)  
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );     // (Reviews tab)
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)

    }

    return $tabs;

}
```

This code works fine to unset or hide tabs from specific products.

**Instead I would like to unset or hide tabs from specific product categories.**

How can I do it for product categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**As the code originally from one of my answers**, it's very simple to make it work for product categories just changing 2 lines and using WordPress conditional function [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id =  $product->get_id();

    // Define HERE your targeted categories (Ids, slugs or names)   <===  <===  <===
    $product_cats = array( 'clothing', 'posters' );

    // If the current product have the same ID than one of the defined IDs in your array,… 
    // we remove the tab.
    if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){

        // KEEP BELOW ONLY THE TABS YOU NEED TO REMOVE   <===  <===  <===  <===
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)  
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );     // (Reviews tab)
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab)
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

The code tested and works in WooCommerce.

> WordPress conditional function [**`has_term()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) accept Ids, slugs or names of your product categories…

Answer (score 2):

Try below code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'conditionaly_removing_product_tabs', 99 );
function conditionaly_removing_product_tabs( $tabs ) {

    // Get the global product object
    global $product;

    // Get the current product ID
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;

    //get all categories
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
    {
            $categories[] = $term->slug;
    }
    if ( in_array( 'Your-product-categories-slug', $categories ) ) {  
        unset( $tabs['description'] ); // (Description tab)  
        unset( $tabs['reviews'] );     // (Reviews tab)
        unset( $tabs['additional_information'] ); // (Additional information tab) 
    }
    return $tabs;
}
```

> Edit for check more then 1 categories

For check more then 1 categories used `has_term()`

```
$product_cats=array('Your-product-categories-slug1','Your-product-categories-slug2','Your-product-categories-slug3');
if( has_term( $product_cats, 'product_cat', $product_id ) ){
.....
}
```

Comment: and sir if we add more category in this code then what is new syntax?

Comment: are you do this for 2 or more  categories?

Comment: yes sir more than 2 categories..actually i have total more than 25 categories

Comment: you need to add condition like   `if ( in_array( 'Your-product-categories-slug1', $categories ) || in_array( 'Your-product-categories-slug2', $categories ) ) {`