# Hide related product tab for specific products in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, related-content

I saw this link: [Unset product tabs for specific product categories in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813697/unset-product-tabs-for-specific-product-categories-in-woocommerce)

I want to hide related product tabs for specific products.

I use this code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wpb_wrps_related_products',22 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab' );
if( !function_exists('wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab') ){
    function wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab( $tabs ) {
        $tabs['wpb_wrps_related_products_slider'] = array(
            'title'       => __( 'Related Products','wpb-wrps' ),
            'priority'    => 30,
            'callback'    => 'wpb_wrps_related_products'
        );
        return $tabs;
    }
}
```

I used "unset( $tabs['related_products'] ); // (Related Products tab)" but there are the tab of related products for specific products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code below, you will have to define an array of products where you want to hide the tab:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wpb_wrps_related_products',22 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab' );
if( !function_exists('wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab') ){
    function wpb_wrps_adding_related_products_slider_to_product_tab( $tabs ) {
        global $product;

        // Define HERE the product IDs where you want to hide this custom tab
        $product_ids = array( 10, 15, 24, 98 );

        // If product match, we return normal tabs:
        if( in_array( $product->get_id(),  $product_ids ) ) return $tabs;

        // If product doesn't match, we add the custom tab:
        $tabs['wpb_wrps_related_products_slider'] = array(
            'title'       => __( 'Related Products','wpb-wrps' ),
            'priority'    => 30,
            'callback'    => 'wpb_wrps_related_products'
        );
        return $tabs;
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested on Woocommerce 3+ and works

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this code in your functions.php file:
         `remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20 );`

Here is documentation of this: [remove related products](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/remove-related-posts-output/).

You can make condition for specific product IDs, and insert code above to condition.