# Condition function for a category of product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, storefront

None of snippets are working for categoreis based query:
 for specific product categories in woocommerce
[Unset product tabs for specific product categories in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813697/unset-product-tabs-for-specific-product-categories-in-woocommerce)
or changing tab text for a particular category which is displayed as special product on display page or single product page.
Codes by LoicTheAztec are perfect as always but i dont know where i am going wrong.

Comment: I have re-tested my code and it perfectly works to remove product tabs on single product page for specific product catégories, **but not for conditionally change the tab contents based on categories…** So what do you want to do, as it's not so clear?

Comment: Sir ' remove product tabs on single product page for specific product catégories' is not working on storefront theme and for tab contents https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46005902/customize-add-to-cart-button-for-a-specific-product-category-in-woocommerce/46008870#46008870 Thanks

Comment: Both tabs and add to cart text doesn't change **Storefront theme**

Comment: Cart? this is not for cart… this is about product tabs (not the content tab it self) in single product pages… I have test everything in storefront theme… Can you edit your question telling what do you want to do in details?